# exec erreur mount php 7 Debian 9

Tags: php, linux

I would like to know how you do to mount a resource (I have to do it this way!) via a php page?
works in debian 8 and php 5.5
not work in debian 9 and php 7

> [pid 14506] read (3, "37 \ n", 7) = 3 [pid 14506] close (3) = 0 [pid
> 14506] brk (NULL) = 0x5618e61f6000 [pid 14506] brk (0x5618e6217000) =
> 0x5618e6217000 [pid 14506] capget ({version =
> _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid = 14506}, {effective = 1 < [pid 14507] getpid () = 14507 [pid 14507] capget ({version =
> _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid = 14507}, {effective = 1 <[{WIFEXITED (s) && WEXITSTATUS (s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 14507 [pid 14506] ---
> SIGCHLD {si_signo = SIGCHLD, si_code = CLD_EXITED, si_pid = 14507,
> si_uid = 0, si_status = 0, si_utime = 0, si_stime = 0} --- [pid 14506]
> capset ({version = _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid = 14506},
> {effective = 1 <[{WIFEXITED (s) && WEXITSTATUS (s) == 0}], 0, NULL) =
> 14506
> --- SIGCHLD {si_signo = SIGCHLD, si_code = CLD_EXITED, si_pid = 14506, si_uid = 0, si_status = 0, si_utime = 0, si_stime = 0} --- close (1) =
> 0 close (2) = 0 exit_group (0) =?
> +++ exited with 0 +++
> ----------: Go to else

```
go.php contains:
# $ output = exec ('sudo /var/www/html/gosuite.sh 2> & 1');
$ output = shell_exec ('sudo /var/www/html/gosuite.sh 2> & 1');
# $ output = system ('sudo /var/www/html/gosuite.sh 2> & 1');
# $ output = passthru ('sudo /var/www/html/gosuite.sh 2> & 1');
# $ output = proc_open ('sudo /var/www/html/gosuite.sh 2> & 1');
```

with gosuite.sh

```
Command passed: / bin / mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.250.185/c$ / mnt / pc-backup / L106529 -o "vers = 2.0, username = agent-backup-ws, password = BcK312Eth2, ro, iocharset = utf8, noserverino "
execve ("/ bin / mount", ["/ bin / mount", "-t", "cifs", "//xxx.xxx.250.185/c$", "/ mnt / pc-backup / L106529", "-o", "to = 2.0, username = agent-backup-w" ...], [/ * 16 vars * /]) = 0
```

Seeing the differences on the two logs at the start of the discussion we see some capabilities issues:

See: getcap / bin / mount
setcap cap_net_raw = pe / bin / mount (here add effective and permit)
getcap / bin / mount gives
/ bin / mount = cap_net_raw + ep

I relaunched the go.php ---> ditto no mounting via the mount command !!!

If a linux specialist can help me?
Thank you